# Append elem to a list replace all list element to the last item I append

Tags: python, list, insert, append

I'm trying to fight really strange behaviour. I'm reading radio frames at my raspberry pi and each frame that I receive I append to the list. I noticed that appending specific element cause replacing all list elements to this specific one.

Code is really simple:

```
    frames_radio_stats = []

    def radio_read():
        global frames_radio_stats 
        recv_buffer = []
        while True:
            if GPIO.wait_for_edge(17, GPIO.FALLING, timeout=3000):
                recv_buffer.clear()
                Radio.read(recv_buffer)
                if recv_buffer[0] == 144:
                    frames_radio_stats.append(recv_buffer)
                    print(recv_buffer)
                    print(frames_radio_stats)
```

prints outputs of first 2 elements looks like:

```
 [144, 55, 201, 226, 0, 0, 160, 131, 240]
[[144, 55, 201, 226, 0, 0, 160, 131, 240]]
 [144, 25, 96, 100, 147, 0, 96, 131, 84]
[[144, 25, 96, 100, 147, 0, 96, 131, 84], [144, 25, 96, 100, 147, 0, 96, 131, 84]]
```

As we see I get different frames (1 and 3 lines) but at the end all list is replaced with last elem. I also tried with "insert" elem instead of "append" but result was same.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is `recv_buffer`? You meant to write: `recv_buffer = []` to make a new list each time.

Comment: @quamrana yea recv_buffer is also list I forget copied that one line.

Comment: Yes, I see. You should move that line to where the `.clear()` is. What you have now is a single list that you keep filling up and taking references to.

Comment: @quamrana yea but that way is much more effective instead of creating all the time new lists. Now I have list that has one elem, I save that elem to another list, clear list and take another elem.

Comment: There are two schools of thought there and you seem to be the only one in your school. Everyone else creates new lists and does not have the problem you report.

Comment: How about *frames_radio_stats.append(recv_buffer[::])* although I understand that you find creation of new lists abhorrent which is a shame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just appending references to the same list over and over again. Each `.clear()` clears the one list.

There are two options. The first is slightly better where you make a new list each time. The second is to have one list, but to save a copy of it each time:

```py
frames_radio_stats = []

def radio_read():
    while True:
        if GPIO.wait_for_edge(17, GPIO.FALLING, timeout=3000):
            recv_buffer = []
            Radio.read(recv_buffer)
            if recv_buffer[0] == 144:
                frames_radio_stats.append(recv_buffer)
                print(recv_buffer)
                print(frames_radio_stats)
```

or

```py
frames_radio_stats = []

def radio_read():
    recv_buffer = []
    while True:
        if GPIO.wait_for_edge(17, GPIO.FALLING, timeout=3000):
            recv_buffer.clear()
            Radio.read(recv_buffer)
            if recv_buffer[0] == 144:
                frames_radio_stats.append(recv_buffer[:])
                print(recv_buffer)
                print(frames_radio_stats)
```

Comment: thanks it was all about that. When I pass that elem using [ : ] I get what I need. So the second solutions works for me.

Comment: Both solutions work equally well, except the first has one less line.

Comment: Not exactly, I get radio frame avarage each 20ms. In first case I will have dozens of unused list after few minutes. When I have one that I clear it's much more efficient. I just all the time was thinking that I add all elem of that recv_buffer list and I was passing reference of it.

Comment: Is that efficiency in terms of time or space?

Comment: mostly about ram usage.

Comment: So how much ram do these lists take up?

Comment: my radio frame has 9 bytes. If I will create all the time new 9 bytes list (I get about 3000 frames per minute) It will take additional 27KB of RAM (and that could works for months). When I have one list it will take all the time 9 bytes

Comment: Although these extra lists will get deleted in a reasonable time frame since python has garbage collection.